# Size of Python IO Stream

Tags: python, stringio

```py
import io
string_out = io.StringIO()
string_out.write("hello")
print(string_out.lenght())
```

I want to know size of `string_out` StringIO. Is there any method in StringIO that support this?

Answer (score 3):

The return value of the [write()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write) is the number of the written characters.

```py
import io
string_out = io.StringIO()
length = string_out.write("hello")
print(length)
```

Comment: The return value is always the currently written characters. Not the wholse string. https://ideone.com/FD7CzG

Answer (score 2):

StringIO.write returns the count of what it wrote:

```
import io
string_out = io.StringIO()
n = string_out.write("hello")
m = string_out.write("helloagain")
print(f'hello is: {n}')
print(f'helloagain is: {m}')
```

outputs:

```
hello is: 5
helloagain is: 10
```